# Comparing dataSet values

Tags: c#, dataset

Im using this code to do display images to edit:

```
protected void Repeater_Outer_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater Inner = (Repeater)item.FindControl("image_Repeater");
        HiddenField Inner_Id = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("HiddenField_Id");

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcnx"].ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmdNew = new MySqlCommand();

        cmdNew.Connection = conn;
        cmdNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Inner_Id.Value);
        cmdNew.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE FK_album = @id";

        conn.Open();
        Inner.DataSource = cmdNew.ExecuteReader();
        Inner.DataBind();

        Label Label_Amount = (Label)item.FindControl("Label_Amount");
        Label_Amount.Text = Convert.ToString(Inner.Items.Count);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

My problem is that each time the repeater runs it connects to the database which makes the page take really long to load (like 10 seconds)
So i want to populate a dataset or a generic List to databind instead. I've tried this:

```
protected static List<string> dataSetImages(){
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcnx"].ToString());
        string sql = "select * from images";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand( sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        conn.Close();
        List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
                string id = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                string img_name = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                string img_alt = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                string FK_album = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            imageList.Add(id);
            imageList.Add(img_name);
            imageList.Add(img_alt);
            imageList.Add(FK_album);
        }
        return imageList;
}
```

*How can i use this and compare FK_album to Inner_Id.Value?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are insistent on using the [RowFilter approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then this is what you are looking for.

```
string expression = String.Format("FK_album = {0}", Inner_Id.Value);
DataRow[] filteredRows = imageList.Tables[0].Select(expression);
```

Here is an article on [DataView RowFilter Syntax](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer, it works like a charm. Your the best :D

Answer (score 0):

better if you can class like below

```
public class ImageDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public string FK_album { get; set; }

}
```

then

```
protected static List<ImageDto> dataSetImages(){
   List<ImageDto> imageList = new List<ImageDto>();
   // add items 
   return imageList;

}
```

then you can call above method and get list of `ImageDto`

```
List<ImageDto> images  = dataSetImages();
```

in your `Repeater_Outer_ItemDataBound` method you can do as below

```
Inner.DataSource = images.Where(i=>i.FK_album == Inner_Id.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. im trying to do something like this: imageList.Tables[0].Select("FK_album like inner_id.value") but im not sure how to go about it and i haven't figured out how to get it working.

Comment: Thank you soo much for you help. Your answer was right but i had to give it to Derek for his detailed answer. Also thank you for making me realise that i need to study some OOP articles :)